# Microsoft Graph API Beta passwordAuthenticationMethod: resetPassword response - "failed", but users are able to sign in

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, reset-password

I am using Graph API Beta version **passwordAuthenticationMethod: resetPassword** to reset user password.
But the API returns status as "failed" intermittently although after that user can successfully sign in with same password.

First sending a POST request to API - */users/{id}/authentication/passwordMethods/{id}/resetPassword* which gives a status 500 intermittently.
But if it gives a response of 202 Accepted, then I query the operation status received in Headers Location of above mentioned API to get the password reset status .

The operation status shows as "failed", but then user is able to login using same writeback password which is confusing.

Comment: first I suspect it is due to beta as this API is under construction. Second how about you try Location url retrieved for operations after some time lag let's say after minute or so?

Comment: @AnkUser Thanks for the comment. If there is a lag in operation, then Location URL gives a status as "running". But final status is "failed".

Comment: you are probably right, I will just give it a try. Other than that i believe it is due to Beta version issue. maybe getting in touch with MSFT on their GitHub page could help you resolve it.